# JSON returned is empty in ASP.NET CORE WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Web API. I have designed the code something like, when a request(GET) comes to the controller , SP is triggered and the data is converted from datasets to data table and returned in JSON format. The problem is when I try to return the JSON the Response becomes empty.

C# Code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTodoItem()
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnect dbConnect = new DbConnect();
            DataSet ds = dbConnect.ExecuteSP2("View_Contacts");
            string results = dbConnect.DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(ds.Tables[0]);
            dynamic json1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results);
            return this.Ok(json1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        return StatusCode(500,ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

The Response:

Sample JSON Required:

```
[
  {
    "Contact": 6860,
    "Title_Movie": "Ayan",
    "Email_": "",
    "PhoneNumber": null,
    "Job": null,
    "Fax": null,
    "Picture_maxi": "",
    "Type": 2,
    "Company_Id": null,
    "School_Id": null,
    "Theatre_Id": null,
    "FirstName": "Stuart",
    "LastName": "",
    "PreferredName": null,
    "Status": 9,
    "Meter_Id": null,
    "Car_Id": null,
    "Business_Id": null
  }]
```

How can I return this sample json . Thanks

Comment: Empty means an empty string. To get that, `json1` itself must be a null. What is the *actual* response? What is the *actual* value of `json1` ? And, if you query a database, why are you trying to convert the result to JSON with `DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet` instead of letting ASP.NET Core do it?

Comment: If you use a library like Dapper or EF Core to retrieve objects with the properties you want, you can return them directly. ASP.NET Core will map each object to a JSON object, each public property to an attribute.

Comment: Maybe it's empty because the result of your query is empty. Have you tried to log the result of your SP call before trying any other conversion?

Comment: Simply i need to return ds.Tables[0]as Json . The response which i get is [
        [
            [
                []
            ],
            [
                []
            ]

Comment: result is not empty

Answer (score 0):

1. Data Tables have an extension method to return them as IEnumerable.
2. If you give the Ok Action an IEnumerable it will return a JSON Object.

Following this, you can change your method to be like this in order to receive the required output :

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTodoItem()
    {
        try
        {
            DbConnect dbConnect = new DbConnect();
            DataSet ds = dbConnect.ExecuteSP2("View_Contacts");
            IEnumerable results = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
            return this.Ok(results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        return StatusCode(500,ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I get an error System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(Int32 maxDepth)

Comment: @JoelAbraham please ignore cyclic json serialization with the following code `services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
   x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: @JoelAbraham Are you using any third-party library for JSON serialization ?

Comment: No I am not using any

Comment: @JoelAbraham What version of .Net you are using?

Comment: I am using .Net Core

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237828/discussion-between-joel-abraham-and-abdelkrim-bournane).